# How can I initialize an object from type with a null value?

Tags: scala

How can I initialize an object from type with a null value?

I want to find any constructors from type and call it with null parameters.

```
import scala.reflect.{ClassTag, classTag}

object Main extends App {
  def init[T: ClassTag]: T = {
    val clazz: Class[_] = classTag[T].runtimeClass
    ???
    clazz.getConstructors.head.newInstance(???)
  }

  class Foo
  println(init[Foo]) // expected: Foo

  class Bar(val value: String)
  println(init[Bar].value) // expected: null

  class Baz(val v1: Int, val v2: Boolean)
  val baz = init[Baz]
  println(baz.v1, baz.v2) // expected: null, null
}
```

Comment: You can initialize object using runtime reflection using 0 arguments (if it has a constructor with no arguments), you can also pass nulls, or 0s, as the values, but don't be surprised if constructor or code using the values will start throwing errors.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: This sounds like an XY question. What is the meta-problem you want to solve? I am pretty sure there is a better way than this.